# ios: Tweeting with SLComposeViewController saves tweet to Draft if Twitter app installed

Tags: ios, twitter, slcomposeviewcontroller

I have an app using `SLComposeViewController` to post tweets. It works fine if Twitter app is not installed on my device (iOS 9.3.2).
But if it's installed, my app says, tweet was posted. And when I open Twitter app is says:

"**Tweet failed to send**
Your Tweet couldn't be sent and has
been saved as a draft".

If I delete Twitter app, all works fine. And it worked fine earlier.
Is something changed in API? How can I tweet without drafts?

The code used to tweet:

```
if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]) {
    SLComposeViewController* tweetVC = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
    [tweetVC setInitialText:t];
    tweetVC.completionHandler = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {
        switch (result) {
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled: …; break;
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:      …; break;
        }
        [vc dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    };
    [vc presentViewController:tweetVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Also I have the following messages in device console:

```
Jun 12 14:40:50 zxPad2 pkd[5937] <Warning>: assigning plug-in com.apple.share.Twitter.post(6.50) to plugin sandbox
Jun 12 14:40:50 zxPad2 pkd[5937] <Warning>: enabling pid=6180 for plug-in com.apple.share.Twitter.post(6.50) 47151597-AD1B-4874-936B-C5A7D1D3E2F1 /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/755F79DE-E26B-4FDD-B34D-C5937E406A3D/Twitter.app/PlugIns/ShareExtension.appex
Jun 12 14:40:50 zxPad2 ShareExtension[6183] <Warning>: host connection <NSXPCConnection: 0x126d44260> connection from pid 6180 invalidated
Jun 12 14:41:19 zxPad2 myapp[6180] <Notice>: 2016-06-12 14:41:19.023|myapp|0x13fd14c90: SLRemoteComposeViewController: (this may be harmless) viewServiceDidTerminateWithError: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)" UserInfo={Terminated=disconnect method}
Jun 12 14:41:24 zxPad2 myapp[6180] <Warning>: plugin com.apple.share.Twitter.post invalidated
```

---

**Is it possible to tweet via `SLComposeViewController` with installed Twitter app ?**

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that when Twitter App is installed, you must log in into Twitter account vida OS > Settings to solve this problem.